# How to get the image height of an image to set another div height

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have images (#myimage) which differ in the image height. There is also an overlay (#overlay), which is supposed to be exactly over this image. I have set the overlay to 100%, which does not work for me because there is #someotherstuff which should not be covered from the overlay..

The problem is, how can I determine the image height of #myimage if I don't know what the height will be? It should variate in the height, though. So the width is 100% and height is auto.

```
<div id="container">
    <img id="myimage" src="image.png">
    <div id="overlay">
        <img src="overlay.png">
    </div>
<div id="someotherstuff">
 // some other stuff not to cover
</div>
</div>
```

css

```
#myimage {width:100%;height:auto;}
#overlay { position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; height: 100%; width: 100%;}
```

Comment: is jquery or javascript a option?

Comment: Why don't you put the main image inside the overlay then and use the overlay image as the overlay element background? This should be done by plain CSS.

Comment: @Benjamin the question is tagged `javascript`

Comment: think its edited just coz it was not b4 i was checking

Comment: Can the HTML be edited / changed? Also, you shouldn't use an ID there if you the image(s) are going to be swapped out.

Comment: So if jquery is an option you can follow the answer of @IVlajid

Comment: thanks for the other suggestions, I will go with the js solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

do this with jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   image_height = $("#myimage").height();
   $("#overlay").height(image_height);
});
```

Comment: Glad to helf @MarcSter :)